# Spock-Spring - How to control when the transaction around a data-driven test is being rolled back?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spock

I'm using the Spock testing framework together with the Spock-Spring extension which allows you to use Springs' @Transactional and @Rollback annotations. Given that I got a data driven test like this:

```
@Transactional
@Rollback
def "Some Test"(int foo) {
  when:
  someDao.insert(foo);

  then:
  notThrown(Exception)

  where:
  foo << [0..100]
}
```

Now what happens when I run this, is that this test is executed 101 times with a different value of "foo". What also happens is, that the transaction is rolled back after each test. What I would like to have is that the transaction is only rolled back after the 101 tests have been run and not after each test. I could of course write a loop inside the test but it would be nicer if I could control when the transaction is rolled back - after each test or after all tests. Is there any way to control this or am I stuck with the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design, Spock considers every iteration of a data-driven feature method as a separate test. The spock-spring plugin honors that, and there is currently no way around it (without modifying the plugin).

Comment: I see. Thanks for confirming it.